# Learning Scala without Java

Tags: scala

I programmed on Node.js long time and decided to study Scala, but I do not know Java. What do you think, is it possible to learn Scala without knowledge of Java? Is this a good choice for the first functional and object-oriented language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to know any Java to learn Scala.  Javascript is both functional and OOP, so technically Scala would be your second such language (although JS is prototypical and scala is classical).

Scala is a nice language, if you're interested then go ahead and learn it - no one reasonable should try to stop you.

Comment: Scala even have an implementation backed by javascript instead of JVM: http://www.scala-js.org/